# Laravel. How would one have a button that when clicked sends an email

Tags: php, laravel, email, sendgrid-api-v3

So I'm using sendgrid and it has some nice documentation. I am not using laravels Mail helper as it is for smtp and I want to use their web API.

If anyone has gone through sendgrid recently I am using their example code (slightly adapted) to send an email at the moment.

```
// using SendGrid's PHP Library
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php
// If you are using Composer (recommended)
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// If you are not using Composer
// require("path/to/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

$view = View::make('emails.tenant')->render();
$from = new SendGrid\Email("Pearlai", "pearlai@pearlai.com");
$subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
$to = new SendGrid\Email("Daniel Cull", "daniel@pearlai.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", $view);
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
$apiKey = env('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
Log::info($response->statusCode());
Log::info($response->headers());
Log::info($response->body());
```

I am new to PHP not just Laravel :D My first question was how would I properly 'use' the sendgrid-api class within my controller? Like when include the Log facade, I would say "use Log;"

My goal is to have a piece of code that will run once a week and when it does it gathers data, generates the emails with the data and sends them to the recipients. I need to look into laravel event handlers right?

EDIT: Error that Occurs when button is clicked:

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function 
(T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
in EmailController.php (line 87)
at Composer\Autoload\includeFile('C:\\Users\\danie\\Documents\\Pearlai\\CRM_Dashboard\\vendor\\composer/../../app\\Http\\Controllers\\Emails\\EmailController.php')
in ClassLoader.php (line 322)
at ClassLoader->loadClass('App\\Http\\Controllers\\Emails\\EmailController')
at spl_autoload_call('App\\Http\\Controllers\\Emails\\EmailController')
at class_exists('App\\Http\\Controllers\\Emails\\EmailController')
in IlluminateRouteCollector.php (line 63)
at IlluminateRouteCollector->getRouteInformation(object(Route))
in IlluminateRouteCollector.php (line 37)
at IlluminateRouteCollector->collect()
in LaravelDebugbar.php (line 769)
at LaravelDebugbar->collect()
in DebugBar.php (line 246)
at DebugBar->getData()
in JavascriptRenderer.php (line 872)
at JavascriptRenderer->render()
in LaravelDebugbar.php (line 805)
at LaravelDebugbar->injectDebugbar(object(Response))
in LaravelDebugbar.php (line 697)
at LaravelDebugbar->modifyResponse(object(Request), object(Response))
in Debugbar.php (line 60)
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TrustProxies.php (line 56)
at TrustProxies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php (line 151)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php (line 53)
at require_once('C:\\Users\\danie\\Documents\\Pearlai\\CRM_Dashboard\\public\\index.php')
in server.php (line 21)
```

Currently stuck on not loading the sendgrid class correctly

Comment: are they providing smtp credential?

Comment: I'm not using their smtp, I use their restful web api. Also, I can't even get to the point of seeing whether the code works, as laravel thinks I am trying to show a page and just gives me the error 
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException

Comment: can you show error because this might be that have not imported that class like `use App\ClassName`

Comment: are you using this : https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

Comment: Yes I am, I did composer require sengrid/sendgrid which took the latest version 6.0. I Then simply did php artisan serve and started making the code and testing it, did I miss a step? Im starting to believe it is a class or route error

Comment: I was a complete idiot and didnt notice the prefix required in the certain section of routes that I had my route specified... Now I'm getting some errors I can actually try and work with :D sorry for the waste of time, I potentially could be updating the question to a slightly different one :P

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you are probably missing a closing bracket.